# got 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape' when using unstack function

Tags: pandas

```
df1 = pd.read_table(r'E:\빅데이터 캠퍼스\골목상권 프로파일링 - 서울 열린데이터 광            장\3.초기-16년5월분1\17.상권-추정매출\201301-  201605\tbsm_trdar_selng.txt\tbsm_trdar_selng_utf8.txt' ,
                sep='|',
                header=None ,
                usecols=[0 ,1, 2, 3 ,4, 11,12 ,82],
                names=['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD', 'TRDAR_CD_NM', 'SVC_INDUTY_CD', 'SVC_INDUTY_CD_NM', 'THSMON_SELNG_AMT', 'THSMON_SELNG_CO', 'STOR_CO'],
                dtype = { '0' : int}
                , encoding='utf-8')

df2 = df1[(df1['STDR_YM_CD'] >= 201301 ) & (df1['STDR_YM_CD'] < 201410 )]   # 칼럼에 조건걸어 빼기
df3 = df1[(df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100001' ) | (df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100002' )
| (df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100003' ) | (df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100004' )
| (df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100005' ) | (df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100006' )
| (df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100007' ) | (df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100008' ) | (df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100009' )
| (df1['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100010' )]

df3_agg = df3.groupby(['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD' ]).sum() #합치기

df3 = df1[(df1['STDR_YM_CD'] >= 201410 ) & (df1['STDR_YM_CD'] < 201606 )]
df3_bc = df3[df3['SVC_INDUTY_CD'] == 'CS100000']
df3_bc_agg = df3_bc.groupby(['STDR_YM_CD', 'TRDAR_CD' ]).sum()
df4 =  pd.concat([df3_agg, df3_bc_agg ]) #축으로 이어붙이기
print(df4.head())
df5 = df4.unstack('TRDAR_CD') #축간 변환
print(df5.head())
df4.to_csv(r'E:\빅데이터 캠퍼스\데이터 분석정리\restaurant business.csv')
```

when I use print(df4.head()), I had a following data frame

```
                 THSMON_SELNG_AMT  THSMON_SELNG_CO  STOR_CO
STDR_YM_CD TRDAR_CD                                            
201301     11947            170760672            14533       10
                  11948           2293679459            50555       65
                  11949            501996924            21138       21
                  11950            314447675            23958       20
                  11953            327033726            11913       37
```

I tried to unstack this data frame into below picture

```
       THSMON_SELNG_AMT                                            
STDR_YM_CD           201301        201302        201303       
TRDAR_CD                                                                
11947           170760672          blah           blah          blah    
11948           2293679459         blah           blah          blah  
11949           501996924          blah           blah          blah  
11950           314447675          blah           blah          blah   
11953           327033726          blah           blah          blah
```

blah means I don't know exact values. 
But, I tried doing this code df5 = df4.unstack('TRDAR_CD')
I got 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'
I don't know why?? 
help me plz~~

Comment: It's evident that there are duplicated values in *TRDAR_CD*. Do you want to aggregate these values together or would you consider creating multiple rows for the duplicated values?

Comment: I find the way~. I fit the problem by using this. df4 = df4.reset_index().pivot_table(index='TRDAR_CD' , columns='STDR_YM_CD', aggfunc=np.mean)
but after that I lose some values. why?? T.T

Comment: It's because those duplicated values get averaged resulting in a single row corresponding to the aggregation. So, if there are 5 repeated entries present in *TRDAR_CD* column, then the remaining columns corresponding to these entries would be averaged to yield a single row of the wholesome aggregation. So, I presume you would like to retain the duplicated entries in separate rows after unstacking?

Comment: oh sorry. I see this message now. no I don't want But I fix it.haha thanks
you are great guy